# How may I correct the number of rows in my files to allow my raster image to be displayed?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, raster

In my attempt to stack multiple raster images on top of one another, I ID my target files:

```
ncfiles <- list.files("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/AH.Error1/Error", full.names = T, pattern = "*.nc")
```

Create an empty raster:

```
bigstack <- stack()
```

Construct a `for` loop to read through my files in the folder and stack the rasters:

```
for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
  fname <-(ncfiles[i])
  f <- nc_open(fname)
  ah <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "DETAILED_RESULTS/aerosol_optical_thickness")
  lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
  lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
  nc_close(f)
  s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
  crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
  ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))
  pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)
  pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)
  exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))
  levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))
  bigstack <- stack(bigstack, pmraster)
  print("test")
}
```

I hit a wall with this error message after only 1 iteration:

```
[1] "test"
Error in data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1428672, 1301440
```

Is the path of least resistance forward to define each file have identical number of rows? If so, how can I correct this error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out what is going on here:

```
s1 <- cbind(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
```

What is the length of `lon`, `lat`, and `ah`; and why are they different?Something is not matching so you are doing something wrong, likely terribly wrong.

**edit**
You were combing data from different files (`f` and `nc`). Now fixed below

```
pmraster <- raster(res=0.1, ext=extent(c(-180,-140,10,30)))  
biglist <- list()
for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
    print(i); flush.console()
    f <- nc_open(ncfiles[i])
    ah <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "DETAILED_RESULTS/aerosol_optical_thickness")
    lon <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
    lat <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
    nc_close(f)
    s1 <- cbind(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
    biglist[[i]]  <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)
}

s <- stack(biglist)
```

Comment: 1 file has lengths of lon, lat and ah = 1428672. The next file has lengths of lon, lat and ah = 1301440.

Comment: You were using `ncvar_get(nc`  --- where it should have been `ncvar_get(f`.  Apparently you have an open netcdf object `nc`  in your environment.